# incorrect text format from showing in html/css from figma

Tags: html, css, fonts, figma

In Figma, I have a design for text that shows the following code:

```
/* Create Account */


position: absolute;
width: 343px;
height: 142px;
left: 575px;
top: 272px;

font-family: Montserrat;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 37px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;

color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);
```

However, when I have the following code in html (with the text having the same font as indicated by Figma, the font of the text appears different in html/css than it does in figma as indicated by the two images I've attached (please ignore the differing backgrounds):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body style="margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;background: #141E30;  /* fallback for old browsers */ background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #243B55, #141E30);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */ background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #243B55, #141E30); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */;">

    <p style="font-family: Montserrat; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.92);font-size: 30px;">Create Account</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Would anyone know why I can't recreate the exact same font appearance in html/css?

Figma Design:
[image: Figma Appearance]
HTML/CSS:
[image: HTML/CSS appearance]

Comment: In your HTML, body height is only 94 px, hence background is repeated. Apply the corresponding height and see the difference.

Comment: sorry which line is that?

Comment: Consider adding `html { min-height: 100% }` to your CSS. And yes, the font should be loaded explicitly.

Comment: ok thank you, that worked. Are there specific backgrounds I will need this for, or should I in general always have html { min-height: 100% }?

Comment: Depends on layout you need. In this particular case it's important to have the gradient to be applied as you want it to (from the very bottom of the page). Remember, default value for height is `auto` - that is, 'be as tall as containing elements require you to'.

Comment: To recreate exact font you need to load font on HTML too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in HTML head:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Add in Css:

```
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
```

Comment: Cheers, the link in the html head works fine, the sans-serif bit isn't needed. Just curious what's the purpose of having the second font?

Comment: Also is there a link that I can use to import all/multiple fonts by any chance?

Comment: you can use google fonts for other fonts `https://fonts.google.com/`

Comment: 'Montserrat' is family-name, sans-serif is generic-family.  Start with the font you want, and always end with a generic family, to let the browser pick a similar font in the generic family, if no other fonts are available.